# How to use two Grid Layouts in one Composite

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, grid-layout, composite

I have some trouble with `Composite`. I have written the following code:

```
final Composite mavniOptionsComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
mavniOptionsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

final GridData textGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 2, 1);

final Label mavniFormatingLabel = new Label(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.None);
mavniFormatingLabel.setText(PFT.MAVNI_HISTORY.getExplanationLabelText());
mavniFormatingLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

final GridData mavniFormatingGridData = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
final Button mavniHistoryRunCheckbox = new Button(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.CHECK);
mavniHistoryRunCheckbox.setLayoutData(mavniFormatingGridData);
mavniHistoryRunCheckbox.setText(PFT.MAVNI_HISTORY.getExplanationLabelText());
mavniHistoryRunCheckbox.addSelectionListener(new mavniHistoryCheckBoxSelectionAdapter());
widgetsMap.put(PFT.MAVNI_HISTORY, mavniHistoryRunCheckbox);

final Button mavniRealtimeCheckbox = new Button(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.CHECK);
mavniRealtimeCheckbox.setLayoutData(mavniFormatingGridData);
mavniRealtimeCheckbox.setText(PFT.MAVNI_REALTIME.getExplanationLabelText());
mavniRealtimeCheckbox.setEnabled(MyPreferences.isWmcDefined());
widgetsMap.put(PFT.MAVNI_REALTIME, mavniRealtimeCheckbox);

final Label toolNameLabel = new Label(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.NONE);
toolNameLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
toolNameLabel.setText(PFT.TOOL_NAME.getExplanationLabelText());

final Text toolNameText = new Text(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
toolNameText.setLayoutData(textGridData);
widgetsMap.put(PFT.TOOL_NAME, toolNameText);

final Label toolVersionLabel = new Label(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.NONE);
toolVersionLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
toolVersionLabel.setText(PFT.TOOL_VERSION.getExplanationLabelText());

final Text toolVersionText = new Text(mavniOptionsComposite, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
toolVersionText.setLayoutData(textGridData);
widgetsMap.put(PFT.TOOL_VERSION, toolVersionText);

mavniOptionsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

new MavniOptionViewer(MyPreferences.getMavniOptionsList()).createViewer(mavniOptionsComposite);

createExpandItem(parent, mavniOptionsComposite, "Mavni Options", com.mavni.ui.Activator
        .getDefault().getImageRegistry().get(IImageKeys.EXECUTE.getPath()), false);
```

But I get the following behavior:

I would like the table to expand to on the full layout. As I understand that happens because I set `setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));` and the table contains only two columns. If I set `mavniOptionsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));` then the table works as expected but the other elements are showing no in there place (like it should be now).

The wanted behviour:

At first I though to create two GridLayouts and insert them into one composite. I tried to search for a way to combine two layouts in one composite but could not find a way. I need one composite because `createExpandItem` works with only one composite. How to solve it?

**EDIT**: In the `MavniOptionViewer` I have:

```
public void createViewer(final Composite parent) {
    commandsTable = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    commandsTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
    commandsTable.setLinesVisible(true);
    final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 5);
    data.heightHint = 120;
    commandsTable.setLayoutData(data);
    final Map<ButtonTypeEnum, Button> buttons = ButtonComboFactory.createAddRemoveCombo(parent);
    final Button add = buttons.get(ButtonTypeEnum.ADD);
    final Button remove = buttons.get(ButtonTypeEnum.REMOVE);
    ...
```

I though of another possible solution. Is it possbile to change `createViewer` so the table will have 3 columns and the `add` `remove` buttons will be on seprated line. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A Composite can only have one layout, you can't change it halfway. It will just end up using the last layout you set for everything.

You could use multiple Composites in a containing Composite.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for your reply. Please see my edit.

Comment: Buttons can't be part of the table. Things like this are always done with multiple Composites. For example often you have a Composite which just contains the buttons.

Comment: ok so is it possible to change the other elements of the Composite to be with 2 columns (and not 3) so they could support the table which needs 2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but GridData has a 'span' argument - which you are already using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make my point more clear. As I understand the table use 2 columns and the tick boxes and the insert boxes use 3 columns. I'm trying to make them uses 2 columns (instead of 3). Is it possible to do so? **EDIT**: A better idea - is it possible to add a third *empty* column in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your main `Composite` with a `GridLayout` of 3 columns and tell the table to occupy all 3 of these columns instead of 2 like you are doing now.

You can do that by changing the `horizontal span` of the table `GridData` from 2 to 3:

```
final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 3, 5);
```

Also, you should not reuse `GridData` objects; from the [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html):

> Every control in a `Composite` that is managed by a `GridLayout` must have
>   a unique `GridData` object.